# How I can Perform certain task in main thread based on the response from other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Main thread(RunnableTest) should not wait for completion of other thread(RunnableExample) to execute the loop to print the numbers from 0 to 4. Main thread and other thread will execute parallelly. Upon receiving result returned from other thread again main thread will be in action mode. How I can achieve that?

**I have a main thread like below:**

```
public class RunnableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //some code
        new RunnableExample();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        // Upon receiving result from RunnableExample thread again main thread will be in action and perform some task
    }
}
```

**Another Thread that performs a certain task:**

```
public class RunnableExample implements Runnable {
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    Thread thread;

    public RunnableExample() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        isAvailable = checkForAvailability();
    }

    private boolean checkForAvailability() {
        // some task
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The local thread created in the constructor of `RunnableExample` does NOT use method `run` of `RunnableExample` and therefore `checkForAvailability` is NOT invoked either.  This thread should have been declared as: `public RunnableExample() { new Thread(this).start();}`

Comment: @AlexRudenko run method will be executed when thread.start() will execute inside RunnableExample() constructor. And I am creating object of RunnableExample class inside RunnableTest class.

Comment: @Srikant, no it does not.  No instance of `RunnableExample` (implementing `Runnable`) has been provided to the instance of thread started in the constructor.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Sorry my mistake!! It's updated

Comment: Addressed the closed reason and it should be reopened now.

Answer (score 1):

> How I can Perform certain task in main thread based on the response from other thread?

If I'm understanding your question, the answer is to use `thread.join();`.  When you fork your `RunnableExample` thread from the main thread, they both run in parallel but then the main thread needs to wait for the other thread before continuing.

```
// this just creates the object, it doesn't start the thread
RunnableExample example = new RunnableExample();
// create the thread object with the example as the Runnable
Thread thread = new Thread(example);
// start the thread running, it will call RunnableExample.run()
thread.start();
// now main does what it needs to do in parallel with the background thread
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   ...
}
// later it should join on background thread, it will wait for it to finish
thread.join();
// it then can read any fields from the example object
System.out.println("isAvailable = " + example.isAvailable);
```

It's important to understand that without the `join()` call, the main thread can't access the `example.isAvailable` field because the memory has not been synchronized.  Once `join()` returns then the main thread is guaranteed to have the memory in `example` updated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Using pulling, would be the easiest.

1. Use Singleton, to have the same shared object between two threads.
2. Use a Lock l witch is used to enter any of the 3 methods.

   a. hasMessage() (look into list)

   b. getMessage() (get out of list)

   c. putMessage(Object elem) (add elem to list)

Whenever main Thread is ready (e.g. every 100 iterations) it checks if hasMessage() is true.